# Printout result to a file

Tags: linux, scripting

I am running few scripts to check size of files and folders on ubuntu.
How can i make these scripts automatic so that they might run automatically at start of day and printout result to a text file
i am new to scripting
Please reply

Comment: The general direction: `man cron`

Answer (score 0):

To printout to a text file is fairly simple.

I'm assuming you're using python.  Correct me if not.

First, open a txt file with write permissions (the second argument of open).
You can then use the .write() method to write to the file.
Finally, it is good practice to close the file afterward.

```
f = open('file.txt', 'w') 
f.write("Hello world")
f.close()
```

For script automation, you're going to want to read up on cron jobs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

actually you can redirect `du` command's output to file, executing by a cron job. The full shell script is :

```
#!/bin/bash
du -H >> /tmp/yourfile.log
```

Notes:

1. look for `du`'s man page for more information on option flags.
2. You may want to have variables in file name for separating daily logs
3. This sounds like a serverfault.com question.